# Modify or configure output of linux command in bash

Tags: bash, archlinux

Currently I am learning bash scripting.
So, I wanted to know how can I modify the output of linux command.
To be specific, I entered a command and after pressing enter, every line should start with an '->' or any symbol.
E.g: In arch-linux, when we use pacman or yaourt to install packages, 
we get "==>" "->" "::" proceeding with some information.
I want output somewhat similar to that.

Comment: I would not recommend doing what you are trying to do, but this would probably work: `exec 1> >(sed 's/^/=> /')`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get what you are trying to do but… are you looking for something such as:

```
function pprint() {
  echo "==> " $1
}
```

Which you can use as such in your scripts:

```
pprint "Hey there"
```

To output the following:

```
===> Hey there
```

Comment: THANKS!  Finally I got the idea